# Django: method call in django models

Tags: django

I have a model like this

```
class User(model):
    username = XXX
    addr1 = xxx

def get_username(self):
    return self.username + 'some message'

def get_addr1(self):
    return self.addr1 + 'some string'
```

and code I want to iterate through each objects and if function with get_+field.name exists then call that method, otherwise return the field itself.

Is there a way to do this? Below is pseudo code:

```
for field in each_obj._fields.itervalues():
    if get_+fieldname exists then:
        return that function call
    else:
        return self.field.name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call `hasattr(obj, 'get_'+fieldname)` to know if the method is there but the best to do that is to actually override `__getattr__` in your class and just let Python do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how I fake python attributes here http://ilian.i-n-i.org/faking-attributes-in-python-classes/ and also check for the alternative solution in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
for var in obj.__dict__:
    try:
        print getattr(obj, 'get_%s' %var)()
    except(AttributeError):
        print var
```